# Alternative norm of $k$-linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, multilinear-algebra, matrix-norms

For a $k$-linear operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times  \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ its norm can be defined as:
\begin{equation}
\lVert T \rVert
=
\sup_{ \lVert x_i \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n} \le 1  \text{ for } i \in \{1, \ldots, k\} }\lvert T(x_1, \ldots, x_k) \rvert.
\end{equation}

If $k=2$ and $T$ is symmetric, i.e. the order in which we put the arguments in $T$ does not change its value, then we can use alternative definition:
\begin{equation}
\lVert T \rVert
=
\sup_{ \lVert x \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n} \le 1 }  \lvert T(x,x) \rvert.
\end{equation}

---

### Question

Suppose now that $T$ is symmetric $k$-linear for some $k>2$. Do we have a similar alternative norm (which might only be equivalent but not necessarily equal to the usual k-linear functional one)?

Comment: It appears you posted [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554555/alternative-norm-of-k-linear-operator) twice. If so, it's best to delete one or the other, preferably before either receives an answer or substantial comment. :)

Comment: Thank you.  I deleted the other question. I'm unsure what happened --- I thought I  posted it only once